# How do I plot output data once I have compiled a program in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, plot, visualization

So I've compiled my **C** code in xcode and it works fine, it compiles. Now I want to plot the output data of said compiled program. What's the best way to do this, or what program should one use to plot data on a mac? If I use ubuntu, I would compile in emacs and use gnuplot, but that doesn't seem to be an option on mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), gnuplot is available on OS X.

You can install it by running the following in your terminal:

```
brew install gnuplot
```